# Http proxy server for unit test to connect to sftp through java

Tags: proxy, java, sftp, tcp, http-proxy

I am successfully able to connect to sftp over http proxy using paramiko library in python using

> ncat —proxy command

Now I want to test it using java junit test. I am able to successfully create sftp server using Testcontainers but unable to open proxy server in my junit . Can you please suggest anything?
I tried using MockServer, Wiremock, Http proxy using request control to connect to socket but none worked.
Any suggestion what I can use?
If I run my unit test against squid proxy I have in my system , test works fine and able to download ,upload and remove record.

> So any proxy server in my java code I can use for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Java) SFTP using HTTP Proxy. Demonstrates how to connect to an SFTP/SSH server through an HTTP proxy. Chilkat Java Downloads. Java Libs for Windows, Linux, ...
Missing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey , Well the issue here is to create a proxy server that is able to establish connection to sftp. Note that I am successful in writing python scripts that connects to sftp over http proxy and want to test that script using java Junit . So in Junit I can create sftp server using Testcontainers and now need to create an HTTP proxy server in junit that is capable of establishing connection to sftp as I will be calling my python script from junit which will he using the ip and port of this proxy server to connect to sftp